# how to create a comment system like stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dataset, comments

I am using asp.net to create a basic comment system , it goes like this:

1. i have two text-boxes for the username and the comment it self, the content of these text-boxes are inserted within a database.
2. retrieve the database content using a dataset to a grid-view.

... everything works great by my question is:

**how do i allow replies to comments like in stackoverflow. like user A says "hi" then user B says "@A - hi". how do i order them so that the reply is below the first comment?**

hope everything makes sense, thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be better to work out which comments are replys, and then insert then into a table with a `ReplyTo` field taking another comment ID. You can work out who is replying to who when the comment is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the comment to the questions.

Then just select from database using the question ID ordering by comment ID.